# WooCommerce: Persisting cart data across different domains but on the same site

Tags: wordpress, session, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm currently developing a Wordpress build which is a single site that can be accessed via numerous domains (e.g. `mystore.com`, `mystore.net`, `superstore.org` etc.). All of these domains point to the exact same site, which is achieved with the following in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

This multiple-domain feature is a crucial concept of the site, but the 'issue' is that it would need as many SSL certificates as domains (currently around 15 domains, and may expand). For example, if the shopper added all of their items to the cart on `superstore.org`, they'd need to check out on `superstore.org` as well.

Ideally what I want is:

- The shopper to be able to add all their items to the cart on `superstore.org` (for example)
- When they click to go to the checkout, it jumps to `mystore.com` (which is the overarching brand, also still the same site; just a different domain)
- Check out and pay.

That way, I'd only require one SSL certificate for the 'parent' URL, rather than 15 different ones (multi-domain certificates are expensive!)

As I understand it, [WooCommerce doesn't use sessions](http://mikejolley.com/2013/12/problems-with-cart-sessions-and-woocommerce/), but instead serialized transients stored in `wp_options`, based on Eric Mann's [WP Sessions](https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager) concept. Since that cart data is in the database, and the user is looking at the same site (just under a different domain), I figured it would be straightforward to 'share' the cart between domains, but it doesn't seem to work that way, based on tests with a site that can be accessed from both `http://mystore.local` and `http://superstore.local`.

I've attempted screwing around with the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` global in `wp-config`, but I don't think I've gotten a handle on that, as it just wipes the cart completely between browser refreshes, regardless of the domain.

WooThemes and others have been [talking about adding WooCommerce MultiSite options](http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/2502035-woocommerce-multi-site-shopping-cart-feature) for at least three years, but the idea posed doesn't seem like *exactly* the same feature, so I'm not sure how applicable it would be (and considering the age of the proposal, I'm not holding my breath).

If anyone has any ideas as to how (or *if*) this is possible, I'd be grateful for the suggestions.

Comment: side note: there are companies like StartSSL that doesn't charge you for creating certificates. They charge you for validating your identity, so once you get that done (at a reasonable price) you can request as many certificates for as many domains as you want

Comment: Thanks for this; at a cursory glance, I could actually only find StartSSL as a service doing something like this. However, along the same lines, I did find https://letsencrypt.org/ - backed by Mozilla, Cisco and the EFF, this looks to bring completely free TLS certificates to servers. I'll have to wait a few months until it's available and see whether I can use it in the way I've described, but maybe this is my best option.